# Averaging specific row values to create new column in R

Tags: r, average, tidyverse

I am trying to combine specific questions to form new combined questions with values that are the average of the questions that were combined. I only want the average value for a specific id. In the example below, I am trying to combine questions 1 and 2 (abc and def) and then generate a column that includes the average of the two values for each participant (indicated by id).

This is an example of what the original dataframe looks like:

```
id  question  qnumber  value
1   abc       1        1
1   def       2        3
1   ghi       3        4
2   abc       1        2
2   def       2        4
2   ghi       3        1
```

This is what I would like the dataframe to look like.

```
id  question  qnumber  value
1   abcdef    1        2
1   ghi       3        4
2   abcdef    1        3
2   ghi       3        1
```

In my actual dataset, I have 17 questions and would like to combine 3 pairs, yielding 14 questions (11 independent and 3 from the combined questions). I do not care if the resulting "question" column has the question names combined in the same style as above, but I thought this would make things easier to understand. The qnumber column isn't very important, but I wasn't sure if it would be easier to combine certain rows on the basis of a number (as in "qnumber") as opposed to on the basis of a string (as in "question"), so I included it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the ever useful `case_when()` from dplyr to take care of that.

```r
library(tidyverse)


df <- tribble(~id,  ~question,  ~qnumber,  ~value,
              1,   "abc",       1,        1,
              1,   "def",       2,        3,
              1,   "ghi",       3,        4,
              2,   "abc",       1,        2,
              2,   "def",       2,        4,
              2,   "ghi",       3,        1)

df %>%
    mutate(question = case_when(question %in% c("abc",
                                                "def") ~ "abcdef",
                                TRUE ~ question)) %>%
    group_by(id, question) %>%
    summarise(value = mean(value)) %>%
    ungroup
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>      id question value
#>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1    1. abcdef      2.
#> 2    1. ghi         4.
#> 3    2. abcdef      3.
#> 4    2. ghi         1.
```

Created on 2018-04-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: When I get to the line starting with "summarise", this just leads to a blank value column. It does not populate the value column. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Do you mean with your real data, or are you saying you cannot reproduce the example here?

Comment: I mean with my real data. However, I don't see a meaningful difference between my real data and your example here, so I am not sure why it would not be working.

Comment: Are there NA values? try `value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: It turns out the "values" were not technically numerics. When I changed the line to summarise(value = mean(as.numeric(value)), it worked!

Comment: What does the "ungroup" function do here? Is it necessary?

Comment: If you leave it off, the final data frame will still be grouped by `id`, since we needed to `group_by(id, question)`. So it depends on what you will do next with this data!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to tackle it, using `tidyverse` and a lookup vector to handle the question combining.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "id  question  qnumber  value
1   abc       1        1
                  1   def       2        3
                  1   ghi       3        4
                  2   abc       1        2
                  2   def       2        4
                  2   ghi       3        1", header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)


# set up named vector for combining (flexible in the real world with more pairs)
lu <- rep("abcdef", 2) %>% set_names(c("abc", "def"))


dat %>% mutate(new_question = ifelse(question %in% names(lu), # add in new column for combination
                                     lu[question],
                                     question)) %>%
    group_by(new_question, id) %>% # group via relevant columns: id and new_question
    summarise(avg_val = mean(value)) # calculate your averages

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   new_question [?]
  new_question    id avg_val
         <chr> <int>   <dbl>
1       abcdef     1       2
2       abcdef     2       3
3          ghi     1       4
4          ghi     2       1
```

Here I dropped the `qnumber` since it wasn't critical and it might make more sense to add it back after summarising.